# jump pad that uses characterController instead of rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

now, ive ben searching for I while, and I cant seem to find a simple answer. what is a simple way to make a jump pad that uses a character controller and not a rigidbody? (written in C#) I want my character to get boosted into the air when he collides with a specific game object. the script my character is using already has gravity so all I need is an upward boost. does anyone know how to do this? I dont have any code I dont know where to start, so please help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Dotween functions? or did you try to change transform.position in Update using your skills.first  I would try Dotween functions like Dojump or DoMove, Secondly I would try this ; transform.position + = Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime;

Comment: hello mustafa! thank you for answering me but I dont know what dotween functions are. I will try the vector3.up I think that will work. also, if I went into my current movement script, and made a line of code that made it so when my player collided with a gameObject with a certain tag it changes the gravity variable to  a negative number, like -7, instead of 7 (which is what its set to now) and then put an else statement that changed the gravity back to 7 when I wasnt colliding with the object, would that work?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a player, he has movement and you want him to jump when he touchs a jump pad. So you need to have a CollisionScript for the player as well as a Impulse on the jump pad. My simplistic way to this, is...

- Before you use this script you need to create a tag called probably jumpPad and then add it to your jump pad in the scene.
  [image: JumpPad Tag]
- Then I would do the Collision Script, that will detect the collision when the player collides with the jump pad. And get the impulse towards y-axis on collision.

Collision Script:

```
public Rigidbody playerRb;

public float jumpForce = 10f;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("jumpPad"))
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);        
    }
}
```

- Then you just need to drag the player Rigidbody for the CollisionScript.
  [image]
- It will look like this
  [image]

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class jumpboost : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag in Inspector the rigid body you want to apply the force to.    
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

    private float jumpForce = 10f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

}          `

Comment: Hello Marto! thank you so much for answering me. however I have an issue. where do I put this script? put it in a collision detection void, but that doesnt seem to work. here is my code above.

Comment: Hello Marto!!!! thank you so much for explaining this si well, but i still have a problem!

Comment: Hello Marto!!!! thank you so much for explaining this so well, but I still have a problem! the reason I asked this question is so that I could have a jump pad that does NOT require the player having a rigidbody, because my players movement script uses a character controller. I tried adding a rigid body to my player and setting it to static, but the jumpPad didnt work. I tried freezing the rotation,  but the jumpPad didnt work.  please help! (also thank you so much for your help!)

Comment: FIXED! I found a movement script that uses rigidbody, added it to my player and the  jumpPad script is working PERFECTLY! thank you Marto for being so patient!  I guess that if you want to make jump pads, just use a rigidbody movement script.